# Show a loader while waiting for the iframe to load according to the link clicked, and hide the loader after iframe has loaded using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe, semantic-ui

I'm trying to show a loader while waiting for the iframe to load according to the link clicked. I use Semantic UI's loader. So far, what it can do is show the loader once the link is clicked. However, the loader will not disappear anymore, even after the iframe document has loaded.

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<div class="drive-link">
    <div ng-if = "!READY.value"> <!-- to check if the link has been clicked -->
        <div class="ui active centered inline loader"></div>
    </div>      
    <iframe name="embedded-iframe" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" iframe-onload></iframe>
</div>

<div class="active content">
    <a target="embedded-iframe" href="{{file.link}}" ng-click="show_file_name(file)"> {{file.name}} </a>
    <div ng-repeat="next_file in files | limitTo:files.length:$parent.$index">
    <a target="embedded-iframe" ng-if="$index > 0 && next_file.category_id == file.category_id" href="{{next_file.link}}" ng-click="show_file_name(next_file)">{{next_file.name}}</a>
    </div>              
</div>
```

**AngularJS code:**

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.READY = {value:true};

    $scope.show_file_name = function(file){
        $scope.fileName = file.name;
        $scope.fileDesc=file.description;
        $scope.READY = {value:false};
    }
});

app.directive("iframeOnload", function() {
    return function(scope) {
        scope.READY.value = true;
        console.log(scope.READY.value)
    };
});
```

I have a directive to iframe, called iframe-onload. I was thinking that if the anchor tag was clicked, it would somehow connected to the iframe (since clicking the anchor tag would show the embedded document anyway), and it would trigger iframe-onload, which would change READY's value. However, this was not the case, and iframe-onload would only be triggered once, when the HTML page loaded.

**Note:**
I'm trying to to stay away from timeouts because I don't think hard coding how long the loader will show is the best way to go.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use simple approach which is that use ng show with your loader code. for example if you have loader in gif image like this

```
<a href="link" ng-click="activateLoader()">Link To be click</a>
<img src="loader.gif" ng-show="loader"/>
```

and then in controller you can do like this

```
$scope.loader=false;
$scope.activateLoader=function(){
    $scope.loader=true;
}
```

Comment: How will the loader disappear? In your example, I want the loader to disappear after the image has loaded also. @Fahad Subzwari

Comment: @limciana make a function of loading picture and then mark $scope.loader = false
Like this
$scope.getPicture = getProfilePicture().success(function(res){
     $scope.loader = false;
}) 
.error(function(err){
  $scope.loader = false;
 console.log(err)
})

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble picturing the code as a whole hehe. May I ask that you provide the entire code for the html, and the controller? Thanks!

Comment: ok. I have this thing in one of my project. In my scenario when get users state is called then users is loaded in table but while data is being fetched from server then loader starts lading and then when table is populated with data then loader disappear. I showing you code in answer section. OK?

Comment: so what I'll do is I'll change the controller that you've shown in your answer to this: $scope.getPicture = getProfilePicture().success(function(res){ $scope.loader = false; }) .error(function(err){ $scope.loader = false; console.log(err) })

and in the html, instead of ng-click="activateLoader()", it will be ng-click="getProfilePicture()"?

Will $scope.getProfilePicture be used? or is it like a holding variable?

Answer (score 0):

this is html table where my data loads.

```
<tr ng-if="!isDataLoading" ng-repeat="x in companies">
                                    <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.CompanyName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.ContactPerson}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.TotalRerrals}}</td>
                                    <td>{{TotalRegistered}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.TotalConverted}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.TotalSalesAgents}}</td>
                                    <td class="text-green"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i> {{x.AccountStatus}}</td>
                                </tr>
<div ng-if="isDataLoading" style="width: 100px; margin: auto;">
                 <img src="assets/loader.gif" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        </div>
```

and here is my controller code

```
User.getCompanies().success(function(res) {

                console.log('All companies', res);
                if (res != null || res != "") {
                    $scope.customers = res;
                    $scope.companies = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                        $scope.companies.push({
                            Id: res[i].Id,
                            AccountStatus: res[i].AccountStatus,
                            CompanyName: res[i].CompanyName,
                            ContactPerson: res[i].ContactPerson,
                            TotalConverted: res[i].TotalConverted,
                            TotalRegistered: res[i].TotalRegistered,
                            TotalRerrals: res[i].TotalRerrals,
                            TotalSalesAgents: res[i].TotalSalesAgents,
                        })
                    }
                }
                $scope.isDataLoading = false;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                console.log('error', err);
                $scope.isDataLoading = false;
            })
```

You can take this as an example. and change this code according to your need.